# Find out what version were proto files compiled with

Tags: java, version, protocol-buffers, proto

I include an external jar to my project with compiled protobuf files to java.

How can I find out with what proto version were they compiled?

To generalize the question - given a class file that was compiled from proto - is there a way to find which version was it compiled with?

Comment: Try their documentation...

Comment: The external jar comes without documentation. I'm only aware that the jar contains .class files that were compiled from .proto files.

Comment: The JAR does not contain this kind of information...

Comment: Might want to look at `META-INF/manifest.mf`, **sometimes** it contains info of the sources or the JAR building process...

Comment: ```YOUR_GENERATED_CLASS.getDescriptor().getFile().getSyntax()```